# Acumatica- How to set enable specific field for edit after using PXSelectReadonly2 attribute?

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

I'm new to acumatica, I have developed a custom screen consisting of form and a grid. In my screen, I have added a button to pop-up a new window using smart panel. This time I need to add values from smart panel to the grid. To get data for the smart panel, I used POline and POrder DAC's. Below is the definition for the view.

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svw8f.png)

Here, I have used PXSelectReadonly2 attribute to define a view. In the smart panel, I have added POLine field - selected to allow user to select values one by one. but this time I cannot select the check box of the selected field, I think the issue is that I have defined the view as read-only. So I need to set enable edit for the specific field selected . To accomplish it, I defined a method like below but it didn't work as expected.

[event handler code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Vbl.png)

Can someone help me on this to resolve this issue please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cache to a regular select, and then on row selected you can execute something similar to this code, which sets the row as read only but the selected field as true.

```
    protected virtual void POLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(sender, e.Row, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POLine.Selected>(sender, e.Row, true);
    }
```